# HighCharts delayForDisplay attribute does not work

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

When switching from one point to another I would like there to be a 2000 millisecond delay so the user can click on a link in the tooltip. I have added the property 'delayForDisplay' which is supposed to address this but it does not work. Although the 'hideDelay' works when you move mouse out of view. Live example:

```
delayForDisplay: 2000
```

https://jsfiddle.net/re0r54cv/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use secure urls in your project:

```
<script src="https://rudovjan.github.io/highcharts-tooltip-delay/tooltip-delay.js"></script>
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fwL9byht/

Comment: Not sure if something changed but the example is not working anymore

Comment: What specifically isn't functioning on your end? The delay seems to be working correctly on my side.

Comment: Sorry, layer 8 problem. I had some tweak on my browser that breaks it, but it is working :)